# jQuery identifer from an href

Tags: jquery

I was wanting to get the id from a series of hrefs...
I got the answers I was looking for - however they do NOT work in the context of my existing code -

The "delete confirm" and "edit dialog call" BOTH work in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RK4Ye/ - BUT NOT when the links are generated thru jQuery.... I don't know what the cause is...but I've removed ALL other js, and these don't work... other pieces of info - the page runs as a tab in jQueryUI tabs...

HELP PLZ.. I don't even know how to find the problem, all the code works previous to the addition of those two features...
and no errors are being thrown....

THE ISSUE: is that both the edit link and the delete link take you to the href, the class selector does NOT catch the click event and stop the request...  (I realize the ajax call will make it impossible to totally duplicate the behavior - but take my word it's returning and functioning properly - but I'll include a JSON packet in case)

```
$( function() {

function loadTable() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',   
        url: 'list.php',    
        dataType: 'json',   
        success: function ( data ) {                
            var items = [];
            var line = 1;

            // clear the table
            $( '#companies-list' ).html( '' );


            // the real data
            $.each( data.companies, function ( key, value ) {   
                var thisRowClass = 'odd';
                if ( line % 2 ) {
                    thisRowClass = 'even';
                }
                items.push( '<tr class="' + thisRowClass + '"><td nowrap>'  + value.company + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.address + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.city + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.state + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.zip + 
                            '</td><td nowrap>' + value.phone + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.contact + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.email + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.jobscurrent + 
                            '</td><td>' + value.jobsdone + 
                            '</td><td nowrap> <a href="m/company.php"  data-identity="' + value.id + '" class="uLink">edit</a> |  <a href="m/company.php?d=' + value.id + '" class="dLink">delete</a> ' +
                            '</td></tr>' ); 
                line++ ;
            }); 

            $( '#companies-list' ).append( items.join( '' ) );                                 

        },

        error: function () {    
            // there's an error
            $( '#message' ).html( '<p>There was a problem on the server... </p>' ); 
        }
    });
}


// pre load my list when page loads
loadTable();



// DELETE CONFIRM
$( '.dLink' ).click( function( event ) {
    var response = confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?' );
    //the following is the tertiary version of: if (response) { return true; } else { return false; }
    return( response ) ? true : false;
});


// EDIT DIALOG CALL     
$( '.uLink' ).click( function() {
    var id = $( this ).data( 'identity' );
    alert( id );

    return false;
});

});
```

the HTML looks like this

```
<div id="companies-container" class="ui-widget">
<h3>List of Companies</h3>
<table id="companies" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content list"> 
<thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>       
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Email</th>      
        <th>Jobs Current</th>
        <th>Jobs Done</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="companies-list"> 
</tbody>

<tfoot> 
</tfoot>
</table>
</div>
```

A sample JSON packet:

```
{ "count": "3", "companies": [{ "id":"2", "company":"Main Customer A", "address":"1234 street ", "city":"Gallatin", "state":"TN", "zip":"30766", "phone":"", "contact":"", "email":"", "jobscurrent":"", "jobsdone":"" },{ "id":"3", "company":"Sub Customer B", "address":"232 road ", "city":"Galatan ", "state":"TN", "zip":"60766", "phone":"", "contact":"", "email":"", "jobscurrent":"", "jobsdone":"" },{ "id":"4", "company":"Sub Customer C", "address":"333 pkwy ", "city":"Nashville", "state":"TN", "zip":"37204", "phone":"", "contact":"", "email":"", "jobscurrent":"", "jobsdone":"" } ] }
```

Comment: `'.d '` there shouldn't be a space there, maybe that's the problem...

Comment: @elclanrs - I removed the space. but it still just clicks on thru....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has me confused, but I think this is what you are after. You can use the `data` attribute and jQuery's corresponding `data` method to grab the values.

So change your html for a link to this

```
<a class="e" href="/somelink" data-identity="23">Edit</a>
```

And your click handler to this

```
$('.e').click( function() {
    // notice that you just use the text after the dash to grab the value
    var id = $(this).data('identity');

    // ajax to pull the details

    // populate form

    // open dialog (with form populated
    $('#myForm').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Does that answer all your after? This is a much easier way than trying to parse the value out the url.

Comment: YES - that is slick and exactly what I'm looking for - however - it didn't work.... the <a href, still behave like a link... just like the delete "problem" - its like the class selector isn't grabbing what it should

Comment: What does `behave like a link` mean? You mean it navigates away from your page?

Comment: yup - that's what i mean... you click it - it the browser goes to the href location...period

Comment: You probably have a script error further down in that code block. Your `return false` then never gets hit. See this example fiddle, works just fine to prevent navigation. That or you have a separate event handler somewhere that causes nav. http://jsfiddle.net/ARXBN/

Comment: For your first fiddle navigation is properly blocked. For your second you are throwing a script error. Try checking your javascript console. You forgot to cast `this` to jQuery - `$(this)` . I still stand by script error.

Comment: Also, use `prop`, not `attr`.

Comment: thx - that made it work in jdFiddle...
but the behavior is still not working in my full page... I've copied and pasted the code that work in jsFillde into the full page....
I don't disagree about the error - but I can't find it... the links are being generated and pushed (meaning they aren't hard coded) ABOVE the stuff we've been batting around - that shouldn't make a diff...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.  You can pass the ID as an id of the anchor link...

```
thing one <a href="x.php?id=1" class="e" id='edit-1'>edit</a>


$('.e').click(function(event) {
 //prevent the browser from going anywhere
  event.preventDefault();
  var id = this.id.replace('edit-','');

  // NOW YOU HAVE THE ID IN THE VARIABLE > id
  // Do with it as you wish


});
```

You've also made a mistake in your delete function.  You don't need to preventDefault()...

```
$('d').click(function() {
   var response = confirm('Do you want to delete this?');
   //the following is the tertiary version of: if (response) { return true; } else { return false; }
   return (response) ? true : false;
}
```

And in your code:

```
<a href="?delete={ID}" class'd'>DELETE</a>
```

Or you can just do:

```
<a href="?delete={ID}" onclick="return confirm('Do you wnat to delete this?')">DELETE</a>
```